# Helm Chart: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: mapping values are not allowed in this context

Tags: azure, kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm, akv2k8s

I am trying to install akv28s secrets using helm template but it fails, I am unable to diagnose the issue in helm, have tried online yaml validators but no help.
Using --debug flags renders me the expected manifest

**values.yaml**

```yaml
akv2k8s:
  enabled: true
  vaults:
    vaultcmms:
      secretkey: secretvalue
      secretkey1: secretvalue1
    vaulttenant:
      secretkey: secretvalue
      secretkey1: secretvalue2
```

**akv28s.yaml**

```yaml
{{- if .Values.akv2k8s.enabled -}}
{{- range $vault, $content := .Values.akv2k8s.vaults }}
  {{- range $key, $value := $content }}
    apiVersion: spv.no/v2beta1
    kind: AzureKeyVaultSecret
    spec:
      vault: {{ $vault }}
        name: {{ $key}}
        object:
          name: {{ $value}}
          type: secret
    {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what is required here, but those two "range" operators, combined with the data you appear to be iterating over, don't make much sense to me. I assume that first range would be iterating over a list, but you don't have a list in your data.

Comment: The `-` to remove the leading/trailing spaces might be messing up your data.

Comment: You got bitten by [this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73642950/225016); it's the leading spaces in your yaml

Comment: Separately, you're not inserting delimiters between those resources, so it's going to see all those ranged text blocks as **one yaml dict** which isn't what you want; you'll want to put `---` before that `apiVersion:` to start new resources for each range

Answer (score 0):

I was making a mistake by specifying the vault value in the wrong hierarchy
It should be like

```
spec:
  vault: 
    name: {{ $vault }}
    object:
      name: {{ $value }}
      type: secret
```

This solved my issue.